# Convert mysql database, really basic

Tags: mysql, converters

I need to take a phpBB database and convert it to a Wordpress database. Both are MySQL. I suspect it is just a matter of figuring out what tables and fields map to the other, i.e. user to user, topic to post, replies to comments. What I want to know is how to automate the process. The problem is the question is just basic enough that google isn't helping.

I've played around enough in MySQL and PHP that I'm sure once I can find a source of how to restructure the data I could do it, but I'm not even sure how to begin this process. So if someone could point me to how to do this type of database manipulation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you're going to use bbpress, this may be helpful; http://wpmu.org/how-to-migrate-a-phpbb-forum-to-wordpress-and-bbpress/

Comment: This is not a basic thing at all, but when I google `phpbb migrate wordpress` I see some promising results

Comment: Pekka, thanks, apparently my keyword choice was crap, because within a few hits of your suggestion, I found this: http://thepetsweb.com/2011/12/convert-phpbb-to-wordpress-to-blogger.html

It's for phpbb2, but I'm sure I can figure out the rest now that I see this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a the following page, it should be able to help you out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

What you likely want to do is have the two databases co-exist, then copy the information from the one database to the other mapping the information appropriately.

With this you should be able to select information from the old phpbb tables and insert it into the new wordpress tables.

Be aware that there might be some additional entries you might need to make to get everything to display and work properly with wordpress. I would suggest trying to create a few pages and see how the information is represented before simply doing the copy and paste.